# Google Cloud Platform Stackdriver uptime check for TCP port : 3306

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I did set up an uptime check on GCP stackdriver to monitoring the TCP port 3306 and it works if I set the firewall rule in GCP by open up the port 3306 with IP range 0.0.0.0/0, but that getting a lot of hackers bot try to hit our MySQL server.

Does anyone know what is the IP range that stackdriver to run the uptime check? so I can put into the firewall rules.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud publishes the IP address ranges via a TXT DNS Resource Record.

[Update 12/18/2018]. Google now publishes a method to obtain StackDriver IP addresses:

```
client = monitoring_v3.UptimeCheckServiceClient()
ips = client.list_uptime_check_ips()
print(tabulate.tabulate(
    [(ip.region, ip.location, ip.ip_address) for ip in ips],
    ('region', 'location', 'ip_address')
))
```

[Getting uptime-check IP addresses](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/using-uptime-checks#monitoring_uptime_check_list_ips-python)

[End Update]

Google changes the IP addresses so you will need an automated tool to process updates. Below I show the manual method to obtain the CIDR blocks. In practice I would write a Cloud Function in Python that processes this list and then update a firewall rule set.

My information source is Google Qwiklabs. I documented this from one of the labs - I don't remember which one.

```
nslookup -q=TXT _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com  8.8.8.8
```

This will return a TXT record:

```
usercontent.com  8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
_cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com  text =

        "v=spf1 include:_cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks2.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks3.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks4.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks5.googleusercontent.com ?all"
```

The last line includes a number of further records to process starting with: `_cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com`

```
nslookup -q=TXT _cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com 8.8.8.8
```

Which returns a block of information that you are interested in. Note that you need to repeat this for each of the `_cloud-xxxx` records returned above.

```
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
_cloud-netblocks1.googleusercontent.com text =

        "v=spf1 include:_cloud-netblocks6.googleusercontent.com include:_cloud-netblocks7.googleusercontent.com ip4:8.34.208.0/20 ip4:8.35.192.0/21 ip4:8.35.200.0/23 ip4:108.59.80.0/20 ip4:108.170.192.0/20 ip4:108.170.208.0/21 ?all"
```

Notice the last line above. This contains multiple CIDR blocks. Repeat as I mentioned above.

```
ip4:8.34.208.0/20 ip4:8.35.192.0/21 ip4:8.35.200.0/23 ip4:108.59.80.0/20 ip4:108.170.192.0/20 ip4:108.170.208.0/21
```

Comment: Hi John,Thanks for the info. and will check it out.

Comment: @MapperkidsLee - I just updated my answer with new information. Google now publishes StackDriver IP addresses.